# Is Addon domain affecting SEO

Tags: seo, cpanel, addon-domain

I am just a learn in the field of SEO and i have a main domain and an addon domains. Both have separate websites. Consider main.com is my main domain and addon.com is my addon domain name which is pointed to a sub directory called "addon".

I can access addon.com by using the following 3 ways.

```
addon.com
main.com/addon
addon.main.com
```

Are these urls are indexed separately by search engines? If so how can i prevent this?

Does Search engine think main.com/addon as a page in the main.com?

I am not sure i need to worry about all these things or just leave it as it is. I searched to google but couldn't find a right answer.

Comment: May i know why the negative vote? Is this off topic or duplicate? or not well framed? Please tell me reasons while down vote so that i will not make that mistake again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late to answer. However, it may benefit others.

`Primarydomain` and `subdomain` or `addon-domain` will not be linked by the search engines automatically, unless you link them purposefully or inadvertently. Except all conditions are true:

1. Your `web root` normally `public_html` has no `index page`
2. `Directory indexing` of your `web root` is opened, eventually
   exposing/linking your `sub-folder` -which is attached to your
   `addon-domain`- to google and entire world.

In that scenario robots.txt solution is not recommended, because search engines may ignore robot.txt rules.

[Reference](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/publish-your-site/does-google-work-with-addon-domains)

Answer (score 0):

Google will only index pages if they are linked to or listed in the sitemap. You can stop the addon.main.com or main.com/addon being indexed by using noindex tags:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

or disallowing it in the robots.txt

The search engine will consider main.com/addon as a page of main.com - if sites are completely separate i'd recommend using a separate domain (preferably a keyword rich domain) but it's up to you really

Comment: If i use meta on addon then addon.com will also not indexed by google. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

We have three domain names with the same content.  For the three domains, it will return a 200 OK HTTP code. It will look like duplicates of the same content. If there is a canonical tag on every page it will be better. 
The best would be to create a redirection on the subdomain panel in cpanel so that at least addon.main.com would redirect to addon.com
Then, you can add a robots.txt to the root path of the primary domain and add

```
user-agent:*
disallow:/
```

so that no robot will visit main.com/addon

Answer (score -1):

Google gives less weight to subdomain hosted site of another domain.
Superbad for SEO

If you are hosting for SEO and love the convenience of cPanel, then forget hosting domains as addon domains.

@Vasanthan R.P.
Its an excellent question, often overlooked by SEO professionals. +1 for you

Comment: Google doesn't care if a site is on a subdomain or on its own domain.